# Minimize jQuery Function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a function that adds change events for form items based on the row name(uses the database to get these).

Heres the current function:

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE storeno = '1' ORDER BY descript";
    $result = mssql_query($sql, $msConnection);

    if ($result && mssql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($row = mssql_fetch_object($result)) {
            $sku = trim($row->mas90sku);
            $JQueryReadyScripts .= "
            $('#newCount_" . $sku . "_row .cases').change(function() {
                var count = 0;
                $('#newCount_" . $sku . "_row .cases').each(function () {
                    count += parseFloat($(this).val());
                });
                $('#cases_total_" . $sku . "').text(count);
            });
            $('#newCount_" . $sku . "_row .units').change(function() {
                var count = 0;
                $('#newCount_" . $sku . "_row .units').each(function () {
                    count += parseFloat($(this).val());
                });
                $('#units_total_" . $sku . "').text(count);
            });";
        }
        mssql_free_result($result);
    }
```

How can I consolidate this into a call that affects every row so that I can get rid of the DB portion and have just 2 pieces (or 1) of code instead of 2 for every row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('*[id^=newCount_]').each(function () {
  var $row = $(this), 
      sku  = this.id.replace(/newCount_(.*?)_row/, '$1');

  function sumValues($elems) {
    var sum = 0;
    $elems.each(function () { sum += parseFloat(this.value) });
    return sum;
  }

  $.each(['cases', 'units'], function (i, type) {
    $row.on('change', '.' + type, function () {
      $('#' + type + '_total_' + sku).text( sumValues($row.find('.' + type)) );
    });
  });
});
```

This has no dependency on PHP, just use it as a regular script.

It uses `.on()` event delegation, so it requires jQuery 1.7+. For earlier versions of jQuery you can use `.delegate()` for the same effect.

I'd recommend giving all your rows a common CSS class, so that the not-so-nice `$('*[id^=newCount_]')` can be replaced with something simpler, but that's a cosmetic change.

Comment: @spyke01 Whoops. That's fixed now.

Comment: Awesome this is exactly what I needed, thanks for teaching me some new jQuery!

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this for both cases and units (Just note, you will need to change the id's of the total counts appropriately)

```
$('.cases').change(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var count = 0;
    $('#'+id+' .cases').each(function() {
        count += parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
    $('#count_'+id).text(count);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between class selectors and id selectors is where id selectors are expected to be unique, class selectors are not.

Using $(this) in the body of your change events, so the operations are relative, you could write one single change event that handles all cases.

```
<input class="cases" id="newCount_123"></input>
<input class="cases" id="newCount_345"></input>

$('.cases').change(function() {
            var count = 0;
            var sku = $(this).attr("id");
            count += parseFloat($(this).val());
            $('#cases_total_' + sku).text(count);
});
```

This also keeps JavaScript out of your PHP, which is hard to maintain and violates MVC principles. Your server-side code does its job of retrieving data and sending it to the client, while your client-side code does its job of dealing with the view.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this works for both of your functions or not. Not sure of the exact markup. but might be worth trying.

```
$('#newCount_' + $sku + '_row .cases, #newCount_' + $sku + '_row .units').change(function() {
    var count = 0,
        thisClass = ( $(this).hasClass('cases') ) ? 'cases' : 'units';

    $('#newCount_" . $sku . "_row .'+thisClass).each(function () {
         count += parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
    $('#'+thisClass+'_total_" . $sku . "').text(count);
});
```